# Jquery, Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I get this error in Chrome 41.0.22 under the Console tab.

The script is this

```
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
var stFailbackDefaults = {
trackScrolling: true,
stLogInterval: 10,
docTitle: window.document.title,
cutOffTime: 900,
trackNoEvents: false,
trackNoMaxTime: false
};
window.total_time = 0;
var stIntervalObj = null;

function TrackingLogTime(tosArray) {
return tosArray[0] == 50 ? (parseInt(tosArray[1]) + 1) + ":00" : (tosArray[1] || "0") + ":" + (parseInt(tosArray[0]) + 10)
}

function stInitializeControlVars() {
if (typeof window.trackScrolling == "undefined") {
    window.trackScrolling = window.stFailbackDefaults.trackScrolling
}
if (typeof window.stLogInterval == "undefined") {
    window.stLogInterval = window.stFailbackDefaults.stLogInterval * 1000
}
if (typeof window.docTitle == "undefined") {
    window.docTitle = window.stFailbackDefaults.docTitle
}
if (typeof window.cutOffTime == "undefined") {
    window.cutOffTime = window.stFailbackDefaults.cutOffTime
}
if (typeof window.trackNoEvents == "undefined") {
    window.trackNoEvents = window.stFailbackDefaults.trackNoEvents
}
if (typeof window.trackNoMaxTime == "undefined") {
    window.trackNoMaxTime = window.stFailbackDefaults.trackNoMaxTime
}
if (window.trackScrolling === true) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        window.onscroll = function() {
            window.onscroll = null;
            ga("send", "event", "Scroll", window.docTitle, "scrolled")
        }
    }, 2000)
}
}
if (window.trackNoEvents === false) {
function startTimeTracking(tos) {
    stInitializeControlVars();
    window.stIntervalObj = window.setInterval(function() {
        total_time += 10;
        if (window.trackNoMaxTime === true) {
            total_time = 1
        }
        if (window.total_time <= window.cutOffTime) {
            tos = TrackingLogTime(tos.split(":").reverse());
            ga("send", "event", "Time", "Log", tos)
        } else {
            window.removeInterval(window.stIntervalObj)
        }
    }, (window.stLogInterval))
}
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    startTimeTracking("00")
})
};
```

The standard WordPress jquery.js is loaded before this script and only once. This script is the last one that loads.

I have tried to end the jquery with or without the semicolon, here

```
startTimeTracking("00");
```

but no luck. Any other options that I am not aware of?

Comment: Why are you declaring the `startTimeTracking()` function inside an `if` block? Does the console not also tell you which line the error is on?

Comment: Yes sorry, the error is in line 57, window.removeInterval(window.stIntervalObj)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no method called removeInterval(), you need to use [clearInterval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/clearInterval) to remove an interval.

So replace `window.removeInterval(window.stIntervalObj)` with

```
window.clearInterval(window.stIntervalObj)
```

Comment: Thanks Arun, the error is gone now. I will check on it later again to see if it is still gone or came back. With previous changes the errors were also gone and came back.

Answer (score 0):

If you look in to the console, there should be a hyperlink on the right side of the error and if you click on that it will take you to the error point. I would prefer put the breakpoint on certain area of the code and debug the code. with `f10, f11, f8` key to see where it breaks.

Comment: Thanks for this info. Hadn't used it before.